# How can I access grpc in cloud pub/sub using python?

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub, event-driven, grpc-python

I want to use google cloud pub/sub with grpc call in python. How can I implement? can someone provide good resources for this?

Answer (score 0):

The grpc protocol is specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/), however I would advise against using the protocol directly.  Instead, try using the client libraries for your specific language as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries).

The client libraries use the grpc protocol under the hood and add on batching behavior and correctly handle authentication.